# SQL Developer date display format

Tags: oracle, date, format, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to change the date display format in SQL Developer, but even after setting NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='ITALIAN' I get this:

```
select sysdate from dual; ==> 21 DECEMBER 18 (wrong, still in English)

select to_char(sysdate,'DD MONTHYYYY') from dual; ==> 21 DICEMBRE 2018 (Italian, correct)
```

There is some different parameter I need to set elsewhere?
Thank you

Comment: you can try this , `select to_char(sysdate, 'dd Month, Day', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ITALIAN') from dual `

Answer (score 2):

Try if the following works for you.

In the menu bar click on "Tools" and choose "Preferences". Expand the node "Database" and click on the sub node "NLS". Set "Date Language" to "ITALIAN" there. Click the "OK" button.